# Elasticsearch Nest : Fetching random documents

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to get random records using Elastic Search NEST client.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compliment @pickypg's answer, here's an example of how to compose a `function_score` query with a `random_score` function in NEST:

```
client.Search<MyType>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .FunctionScore(fs => fs
            .Query(fq => fq.MatchAll())
            .RandomScore()
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: It seems the API has changed. This works now: `client.Search<MyType>(s => s
 .Query(q => q
  .FunctionScore(fs => fs
   .Query(fq => fq.MatchAll())
   .Functions(f=>f
    .RandomScore(
     Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    )
   )
  )
 )
);`

Answer (score 2):

ES 7.x

**NEST Way :**

```
var result = _elastic.Search<dynamic>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
        .FunctionScore(fs => fs.Functions(f => f.RandomScore())
        .Query(fq => fq.MatchAll()))));
```

**raw query way :**

```
 GET index-name/_search
    "size": 1,
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
                "query" : { "match_all": {} },
               "random_score": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an Elasticsearch question than one related to NEST. With that in mind, you can do this using a [`random_score` function](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_random) in Elasticsearch. `random_score` is one of the many `function_score`s available in Elasticsearch -- including scripted scores -- and it can be used to control the `_score` for each matching document.

Relative to Elasticsearch's REST API

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/your-index/your-type/_search -d '{
  "query" : {
    "function_score": {
      "query": { "match_all": {} },
      "random_score" : { }
    }
  },
  "size" : 1
}'
```

You can control the seed used by the random number generator *or* you can create your own random function score. The current `random_score` implementation loads the `_uid` field from the index (the unique identifier), which the documentation notes can be memory intensive.